# Knockout: Change event does not work

Tags: knockout.js

On my webpage I have the following 2 inputs, the first one is textbox populated by autocomplete, and the second one is an ordinary textbox;

```
       <td style="width: 380px">
                <input type="text"
                       data-bind="enable: enableContract, jqAuto: {
                            source: getOptions,
                            value: SelectedContract,
                            labelProp: 'Label',
                            inputProp: JobDescription
                            }"
                       style="width: 99%;" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 160px">
                <input type="text"
                       data-bind="value: Description, enable: enableContract, event: {change: disableContractIfConditionsMet}"
                       style="width: 99%;" />
            </td>
```

Just to complete the picture, when the autocomplete textbox is populated, the following 2 fields are populated;

```
self.ContractId = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    if (self.SelectedContract() != null) {
        return self.SelectedContract().Id;
    }

    return 0;
});



self.JobName = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    if (self.SelectedContract() != null) {
        return self.SelectedContract().JobName;
    }

    return "";
});
```

the value of the autocomplete textbox itself is set as follows;

```
self.SelectedContract = ko.observable(self.JobDescription());
```

What is not working is the change event on the second textbox. The intention is that when you enter the text "Sick" for example, it disables and clears the previous textbox (and set the ContractId to zero and JobName to empty - not coded yet). But this event is not executed when I leave the Description textbox.
How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest not using the `change` event, but subscribing to the `value` bound observable instead.

```
var disableContractIfConditionsMet = function(currentDescription) {
  // Perform condition logic and set enable/disable states here
};

this.Description = ko.observable();
this.Description.subscribe(disableContractIfConditionsMet);
```

You can probably even create an `enabled`/`disabled` *computed* method that automatically updates based on the value of `Description`. I don't really understand the exact UI requirements though, so it's hard for me to write those...

---

An example of how you'd use a computed:

```js
ko.applyBindings(new function() {
  
  var REQUIRED_VALUE = "test";
  
  this.secondInputValue = ko.observable("");
  this.firstInputEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.secondInputValue()
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(REQUIRED_VALUE);
  }, this);
  
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

input:disabled {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="enable: firstInputEnabled">
<label>
  This input enables the first one if you type something containing "test"
<input data-bind="textInput: secondInputValue">
</label>
```

Comment: I changed the databind to "enable: disableContractIfConditionsMet" and I run the code which executed as expected, but the UI did not change. Incidentally I tried using computed and that did not work. I find there is very little documentation on Knockout subscriptions.

Comment: If you want the UI to update automatically you have to use a `ko.observable` or `ko.computed` in your `enable` data-bind. The example I've included in my answer expects `self.enabled = ko.observable()` which can be set to either `true` or `false` inside `disableContractIfConditionsMet`. E.g.: `self.enabled(currentDescription === "Sick")`

Comment: I've included an example of a `computed` enable approach. If you need help crafting the code for your specific case, it would help if you show some more of your viewmodel (e.g. `disableContractIfConditionsMet` and `enableContract`)

Comment: Thank you for your help, the computed solution worked. This surprises me as I thought I tried it before, but I must have got something wrong. Anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say why your code isn't working, but here's a snippet that uses the `change` event to do what you describe, at least as far as disabling. I don't understand the `jqAuto` binding, so I don't know how to clear the value.

```js
self = {
  SelectedContract: ko.observable(),
  JobDescription: ko.observable(),
  enableContract: ko.observable(true),
  Description: ko.observable('descrip'),
  disableContractIfConditionsMet: () => {
    if (self.Description() === 'Sick') {
      self.enableContract(false)
    }
  }
};
self.ContractId = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  if (self.SelectedContract() != null) {
    return self.SelectedContract().Id;
  }

  return 0;
});
self.JobName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  if (self.SelectedContract() != null) {
    return self.SelectedContract().JobName;
  }

  return "";
});

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="enable: enableContract, jqAuto: {
                            source: getOptions,
                            value: SelectedContract,
                            labelProp: 'Label',
                            inputProp: JobDescription
                            }" style="width: 99%;" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description, enable: enableContract, event: {change: disableContractIfConditionsMet}" style="width: 99%;" />
</div>
```

Comment: jqAuto comes from the Knockout jqAutocomplete pluggin.